# Memory efficient majority voting cell wise for large matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of array, I would like to extract the frequent elements in every cell.

For example, for 3 array

arr 1

```
0,0,0
0,4,1
0,1,4
```

arr 2

```
0,0,0
0,7,1
0,1,1
```

arr 3

```
5,0,0
0,4,1
0,1,1
```

The most frequent element for each cell would be

```
0 0 0
0 4 1
0 1 1
```

May I know how to achieve this with Numpy? And in actual case, the list of array can be up to 10k in shape.

The list of array are defined as below

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,4,1],[0,1,4]])
arr2=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,7,1],[0,1,1]])
arr3=np.array([[5,0,0],[0,4,1],[0,1,1]])
arr = np.stack([arr,arr2,arr3], axis=0)
```

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve]

Comment: In my humble opinion, the OP is suffice and crystal clear about the intended objective.

Comment: It would be useful to at least add `np.array(...)` around your data to make sure we're all on the same page

Comment: I agree with you on this. The post has been updated to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `stack` the arrays into a large matrix and then use `scipy.stats.mode` along the axis of interest:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
arr1 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,4,1],
        [0,1,4]]
arr2 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,7,1],
        [0,1,1]]
arr3 = [[5,0,0],
        [0,4,1],
        [0,1,1]]

arr = np.stack((arr1, arr2, arr3), axis=0)
output = scipy.stats.mode(arr, axis=0).mode[0]
print(output)

# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 4 1]
#  [0 1 1]]
```